# how to create one to one relationship in entity .net framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, relationship, one-to-one

Hi I want create one to one relation ship with entity .net framework in C# windows form. but i get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: 'One
> or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> person_pos_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
> 'person_pos_Source' in relationship 'person_pos'. Because the
> Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound
> of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'. '

this is my code for person and their position table:

```
   public class pos
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid id { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        public virtual person person { get; set; }

    }





 public class person
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid id { get; set; } 
        
         [Required, Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required, Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string family { get; set; }
        public int? age { get; set; }

        public DateTime Createdata { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("pos")]
        public Guid posId { get; set; }

        public virtual pos pos { get; set; }


    }
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are fundamentally wrong here.

A 1:1 relationship can be achieved by having the primary of another table as the foreign key and also for the other referred table (non-nullable).

So you should have your relationship like this.

```
public class Class1
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual Class2 Class2 {get;set;}
}

public class Class2
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Class1")]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual Class1 Class1 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: i change my code as your sample but i get this error now: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'id' on type 'BE.pos' is not valid. The navigation property 'person' was not found on the dependent type 'BE.pos'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.'

Comment: @sadegh show you the code, I think you need to change the order of the tables while creating them

Comment: I finally got it. now I can create one to one relationship in both way. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use fluent API for that (you need to override `OnModelCreating` method of `DbContext`):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<pos>()
        .HasOne<person>(x => x.pos)
        .WithOne(x => x.person)
        .HasForeignKey<person>(ad => ad.posId);
}
```

Comment: can you explain more please. i do not know how to use this.

Comment: @sadegh Please refer [to this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx)

Comment: I finally got it. now I can create one to one relationship in both way. thank you for your help.